# Spotlight Importer - Category

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight, spotlight-plugin

I'm working on a Spotlight Importer which works quite nice.

But I haven't been able to figure out how to display the results in their own category.
As of now, they are listed under 'Documents' - (Miles Davis - Sanctuary)

Any ideas on where to start searching for this?  Already check the Apple Spotlight Docs.

[image: spotlight screenshot]